# How to pass argument in hyperLink navigateUrl inside a repeater

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, hyperlink, repeater

I am working on a video portal application, I have use a html template for designing. I have use `asp:Repeater` control display all the video images. When a specific image is clicked the page is redirected to video detail page.
Here is my html code,

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rp_videos" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 small-grid">
            <div class="vid-img-holder wow pulse" data-wow-duration="1s">
                <div class="top-shadow">
                    <span>'<%# Eval("time_before") %>'</span>
                    <span>From <a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a></span>
                    <span><i class="fa fa-eye"></i>'<%# Eval("views") %>'</span>
                </div>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="hl_video_img" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Views/VideoDetail.aspx">
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_file" runat="server" Value="'<%# Eval("file") %>'" />
                    <asp:Image ID="img_video_image" runat="server" class="img-responsive hidden-sm hidden-xs" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image") %>' AlternateText="video_thumb" />
                    <img class="img-responsive hidden-md hidden-lg" src="../images/main-vid-image-smmd-1.jpg" alt="video_thumb" />
                    <span class="play-icon">
                        <img class="img-responsive play-svg svg" src="../images/play-button.svg" alt="play" onerror="this.src='images/play-button.png'" />
                    </span>
                </asp:HyperLink>
                <h3 class="vid-author">
                    <span>By <a href="~/Views/Profile.aspx" title="Posts by admin" rel="author">'<%# Eval("publisher_name") %>'</a>
                    </span>
                     <a href="video-detail.html">'<%# Eval("title") %>'</a>
                </h3>
                <div class="bottom-shadow"></div>
                <div class="overlay-div"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I want to pass the detail of a video which is clicked, here is the view of all video page.

[image]

Comment: You have done all that and you dont know how to pass one more parameter ?

Comment: Yes I have get and display all the videos, now i want that when a specific video is been clicked to play, then it should be redirected to new page where i want to play that video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your hyperlink add the code in the Navigate URL (*you have to use single quotes*)

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hl_video_img" runat="server" NavigateUrl='~/Views/VideoDetail.aspx?videoid=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"video_id")%>'>
```

So you generate the proper link and you pass the id of the video you want to open.

Now in your **VideoDetail.aspx** add the code to get the parameter from the Query String in your page_load function

```
  if (Request.QueryString.HasKeys())
  {
    try 
    {
       //get the id from query string
       string videoID = Request.QueryString["videoID"].ToString();
    }
    catch {  }
 }
```